# How to register a JSF 1.2 PhaseListener in a Servlet.init()?

Tags: java, jsf, phaselistener

Is it possible? `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular servlet isn't initialized/called during a JSF request, so there's no means of a `FacesContext` in a servlet. Only when the request URL matches the `FacesServlet`, then there's a `FacesContext`. You should register the `PhaseListener` in `faces-config.xml` or in a JSF managed bean instead. Consider doing it in the (post)constructor of an application scoped managed bean.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although it's what I feared to hear. I was looking for a solution that does not need to modify faces-config.xml.

Comment: You're welcome. Since JSF 2.0 it's by the way possible to instantiate application scoped beans eagerly without the need to reference it in any view or other managed bean.